# Relative growth, adding a constant rate

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Hey I was just confused on how I should be approaching this question I have for homework.
I have
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = kP\left(1-\frac{P}{M}\right).$$

Where $k$ is relative growth, $P$ population, $M$ carrying capacity. If I were to add a constant rate for example, $Z$, that would increase the population growth of this function, would I add $Z$ within the brackets or outside of the brackets?

*edit: thanks for the help everyone, sorry I am a newb !

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your question is not clear. What does "new constant rate" mean? In this logistic equation $k$ is usually called the rate. Please clarify with an [edit] to the question, not in a comment. Use mathjax instead of an image: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are going for.

**Case 1** - Add inside the brackets

\begin{align*}
\frac{dP}{dt} &= kP\left(1-\frac{P}{M}+Z\right)\\
&=  kP-\frac{kP^2}{M}+kZP\\
&= (1+Z)kP-\frac{kP^2}{M}\\
&=(1+Z)kP\left(1-\frac{P}{(1+Z)M}\right).
\end{align*}
Note that this basically corresponds to scaling both the relative growth rate and the carrying capacity by the same factor, which I don't think is what you are trying to do.

**Case 2** - Add outside the brackets

$$\frac{dP}{dt} = kP\left(1-\frac{P}{M}\right) + Z.$$

Here we are increasing the overall growth rate of the population by a constant of $Z$ individuals per unit time, which I think is probably what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer and sorry for the ambiguity of the question, I am trying to find the the rate at which the population increases per time through Z, so I am guessing that would be case 2 !

Comment: Glad I could help! If that answers your question feel free to "accept" it.